# How do I make a panel that I can select bones in a rig

Tags: bones, select

So what I need is to have some bones type thing off to the side that I can use to chose bones.

Here's what I want similar to the mike rig on blend swap.

Are there any tutorials or something else that I can use to make this?

I have a freelance client that needs this for their rig and I can't figure out how to do this.

.[image]

Thanks for helping.

Comment: This is an Auto Rig Pro feature (payed addon), which is not so easy to build without. I personally find it quite unconfortable and I suggest you to have two 3D windows open: one without overlays (so you don't have your character covered by bone shapes) and one with overlays, for selecting purposes.